# $X \in\operatorname{Im}(C) + E [X]$ almost surely?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory

Given a random vector $X = (X_1,..., X_n)$, where each random variable $X_i$ has finite variance, show that $X \in\operatorname{Im}(C) + E [X]$ almost surely , that is $ P(X \in \operatorname{Im} (C )) + E [X])$ = 1, where $C$ is the variance matrix of $X$.

We assume that Im(C) is the image of the covariance matrix, $E [X]$ is the expected value.
We also assume that $X = (X_1,..., X_n) \in L^2$

I have to do this proof but I'm stuck. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Looks like you already posted this one and got closed. Add details, context and what you tried.  What is $\textrm{Im}(C)$? What's the measure space?

Answer (score 1):

Note that by subtracting $E(X)$, you may assume without loss of generality that $E(X)=0$ and $C= E(XX^\top)$. Try to proceed as follows. If $rank(C)=n$, then the result clearly holds (why?). If $rank(C)= r <n$, then show that there must exist $r$ variables ${\bf X}_r = (X_{i_1},..,X_{i_r})$ such that $X_j = \sum_{k=1}^r \alpha_{j,k}X_{i_k}$ almost surely for all $j$, and the covariance of ${\bf X}_r$, $C_r$, has full rank. In particular, ${\bf X} = A {\bf X}_r$, where $A$ is a matrix comprised of the coefficients $\alpha_{j,k}$ and $C = A C_r A^\top$. Conclude from this that ${\bf X} \in Im(C)$ almost surely, since ${\bf X}_r \in Im(C_r)$ almost surely. Clearly there are some details to fill in here, but I think this hint gets you most of the way.